# C# HDFS File upload timeouts

Tags: c#, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm using the Microsoft.Research.Peloponnese.WebHdfs to write file to HDFS. But there seems to be a 100s timeout for uploading files using this. I did not find any way I can change this timeout.

```
using (var hdfs = new WebHdfsClient(user, port))
{
   using (Stream writeStream = hdfs.GetDfsStreamWriter(writeFileURI))
   {
     using (Stream readStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(inFile))
     {
         readStream.CopyTo(writeStream );
     }
   }
}
```

Or Is there a better way to write files to HDFS using C#?

Comment: I did some googling, apparently GetDfsStreamWriter calls GetDfsStreamWriterAsync under the hood. [The latter accepts a timeout argument](https://github.com/MicrosoftResearch/Peloponnese/blob/9f721890c75922af789fbbae530c214e175cd517/AzureStorage/DfsClient.cs#L429).

Comment: Yeah. But I'm using this one https://github.com/MicrosoftResearch/Peloponnese/blob/9f721890c75922af789fbbae530c214e175cd517/WebHdfs/WebHdfs.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a modified version of [WebHdfs class](https://github.com/MicrosoftResearch/Peloponnese/blob/9f721890c75922af789fbbae530c214e175cd517/WebHdfs/WebHdfs.cs)

Modify GetDfsStreamWriter method to have a Timeout property set for the PUT request.

```
put.Timeout = 8000000;
```